# Need Apache commons-lang3 as dependency of an Eclipse plugin built with Tycho

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, tycho

I'm having one of those nights...
I'm developing an Eclipse plugin using Tycho (the Maven extension), and at some point I wanted simply to use the class `StringUtils` from `org.apache.commons`. After some research, the only way that I could find is the following code in my pom.xml parent file:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
          <environments>
            <environment>
              ...
```

This didn't work, and any other solution that I tried didn't work either.
I'm using Maven for the first time, so maybe I'm missing something (or a lot of things)...
Does anyone have an idea? I'd be very thankful :o)

Comment: Are you able to make changes to the parent POM?

Comment: yes I am. I have full control on the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. So if it doesn't work, you are probably missing the dependency declaration in the MANIFEST.MF. To do this, e.g. add `Require-Bundle: org.apache.commons.lang3` in that file.

Background: A dependency in the POM doesn't automatically mean for Tycho that your bundle also automatically has this dependency. It only means that the artifact will be added to the target platform (given that `pomDependencies=consider` is configured and the artifact is an OSGi bundle - both is true in your case). Once it is in the target platform, it can be used to resolve the dependencies declared in your bundle's MANIFEST.MF.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to "upgrade" to using a [target platform](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) to define your target.

How are you achieving this dependency in your development environment? If you are not using a target platform, you are inheriting whatever plug-ins are installed in your development (that is the default target platform).

### Create Target Platform

First create a target platform. I recommend using the [Target Platform Definition DSL and Generator](https://github.com/mbarbero/fr.obeo.releng.targetplatform) to create and edit the target platform.

The `tpd` file will look something like this for orbit

```xml
target "name"

with source requirements

location "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20150519210750/repository/" mars-orbit {
    org.apache.commons.lang3
}

location "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars" mars-release {
    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
    org.eclipse.equinox.executable.feature.group
    org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group
    org.eclipse.ui.trace
    org.eclipse.pde.feature.group
}
```

This example uses the already created OSGi bundles for third-parties. You can choose which release of orbit and browse all the available packages on the [Orbit Site](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/). You can also use auto-completion in the `tpd` editor.

### Tycho Using Target Platform

Place the `target` file in a new plug-in. Name the target file the same as the plug-in. (e.g. `com.example.releng.targetplatform.target` is the name of the target file in this example.)

In this project, a pom that looks like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>com.example.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
  <packaging>eclipse-target-definition</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.releng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../com.example.releng</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

You can configure (in your releng pom.xml) the target configuration like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>eGui</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.example.releng.targetplatform</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </artifact>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

### Tutorial

Have a look at [Code & Me's excellent tutorial](http://codeandme.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/tycho-build-8-using-target-platform.html) on Tycho, it goes into more detail and over many steps goes from new project to a complete Tycho.

Comment: thank you for your answer. actually, all I needed to do is to add this line to my MANIFEST file: Require-Bundle: org.apache.commons.lang3 . thanks anyway

Comment: Hi again Jonah, I tried to solve my problem using a target platfom by doing exactly what's described on the **Code & Me**'s Tutorial, but I get this Error : [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact test:com.codeandme.tycho.releng.targetplatform:target:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1].... any idea what might cause that?

Comment: @Cambiasso Please post as a *new* question and with the full trace (questions are more readable and then someone else may also know the answer better/sooner than me).